# How to Get jQuery value with help of ajax in PHP and refesh page after getting value?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery DateRangePicker in PHP trying to send date in PHP but page is not refreshing neither value is Get with ajax although it is showing successful.

jQuery -

```
     $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', (e, picker) => { 
     var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');  
 var val = startDate;
        $.ajax ({
            url: "testing.php",
            data: { val : val },
            success: function( result ) {
                alert("Hi, testing"); 
            }
        });
```

PHP -

```
echo ( $_GET['val'] );
```

Comment: Are you sure `startDate` has any value ? Did you check that ?

Comment: Yes startdate= picker.startdate.format('YYYY-MM-DD) it will return the selected date from the jQuery date picker.

Comment: Your code seems okay to me, Still can you put `alert(startDate)` and see if that show value or not inside your event handler

Comment: Yes startdate giving selected date value like 2020-10-10